# Is this possible to make database changes for two same posgres database within same server at same time?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PGAdmin UI for Postgresql.

I have two database '**demo**' and '**testing**'(for testing) and  both database has same  schema and data.when there is any changes in database I have repeat all process for both database.for example if data type of column change i have to run this query script for both.

Is there any work around in postgres that I made any changes in first("demo") database will reflect in other ("testing") database.

I think there is 'template1' template which store all database changes and object as per my knowledge.

using this can I achieve this ? or Is there any other way to do this?

thanks in advance !

Comment: You should automate those changes, e.g. using something like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Template1 dose NOT store changes made to any database or object. It is used to create a new database and that database will contain any changes made in template1. This would probably be best done via your standard DB migration process.